# What's the difference between a RAID enclosure, and a JBOD enclosure connected to a RAID controller

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, raid, sas

I've currently got an Areca ARC-1222 raid controller card connected to an iStorage Pro JBOD enclosure via miniSAS, on a mac, used for video editing. I'm speccing out a PC to replace it and have become totally baffled by the RAID options.

According to the guff the iStorage Pro has an SAS expander. So am I correct in thinking that the chain looks like

```
pci bus->RAID controller->MiniSAS->SAS expander->SATA-HDD
```

What's the [dis]advantage of this compared to a RAID enclosure with the RAID controller built in, or a raid controller card connected to something like [this](http://www.macfixit.com.au/stardom-sohotank-0gb-8-bay-mini-sas-drive-enclosure.html) enclosure, which is a lot cheaper, but doesn't mention anything about a SAS expander. Or for that matter an internal RAID card connected to internal disks, ahich seems to be the cheapest option of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combined RAID-enclosure takes data with up to 6 Gb/s from your PC and the RAID controller has most probably direct channels to each drive so it can write the data simultaneously.

If you have a RAID controller and an enclosure and have both connected by a single cable, the controller has to send the data to write for each drive separately. This generates overhead and - e.g. for a RAID1 - decreases writing performance by 50%. Because you can't squeeze 2x 6Gb/s (=data for both drives) through a single 6G cable.

Example (RAID1):

Combined RAID-Enclosure:

```
                           ,---6G---> Disk0
PC ---6G---> Controller --<
                           `---6G---> Disk1
```

Separate Controller and Enclosure (with Expander):

```
                                                      ,---3G---> Disk0
PC ---6G---> Controller ---6G (2x 3G)---> Expander --<
                                                      `---3G---> Disk1
```

Reading performance shouldn't be different, though, as it doesn't matter from which drive it is read - both contain the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about enclosures that don't have the expander? Are they just hard wiring the 4 channels that come down the mini-sas cable into the drives, a bit like one of those internal sas->sata splitter cables?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all enclosure devices using `lsscsi -gt | grep encl`.
2. Execute sg_inq command on each enclosure device. For example: `sg_inq /dev/sgx`.
3. Check whether the *Device_type=13* (indicate its enclosure device) and

   - If *EncServ=1* then it is a JBOD controller.
   - If *EncServ=0* then it is a RAID controller.